# Tool.jar not found in JDK

Tags: java, ant, path

I'm trying to check in ant is properly installed but I keep running into this error that tool.jar is not found. I have the path going to the JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin) but it seems that the tool.jar find simply isn't there. Do I need to redownload the JDK or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking for 'tools.jar' and not 'tool.jar'. There was a distribution of JDK 1.8 that was missing tools.jar, but that problem was associated with an early release version. Anything you've downloaded recently shouldn't have that issue.